Is it possible to use server aliases with Vagrant?
I have configured Vagrant to work with VMWare (vmware_desktop) provider. My host machine is running on Windows 11, my guest virtual machine uses Linux/Ubuntu 22.04. I have several apps on my guest configured with Apache to run on one IP adress and one port (127.0.0.1:80), the difference is only in project folder and in ServerAlias, which is defined in /etc/hosts file. Firewall has correct setup for sure.
Apache configuration:
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias first_alias
   ServerAdmin admin@test.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/first_app/public
   <Directory /var/www/html/first_app>
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/first_app/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/first_app/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

/etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   first_alias
127.0.0.1   second_alias
127.0.0.1   third_alias

Vagrantfile:
(I removed synced_folders and ssh from this example to make it shorter.)
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.box = "file:///C:/VM/box_name.ova"
   config.vm.hostname = "local_dev"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:80, host:80
   config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
   config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |vmware|
      vmware.memory = "8192"
      vmware.cpus = 2
   end
end

If I try it in my web browser on guest machine, I see localhost as default app (localhost:80) with links to other apps (first_alias:80, second_alias:80, third_alias:80) and the redirection on them works fine.
On my host machine, I can see only localhost:80 and correct links, but the redirection doesn't work. I cannot ping any of the aliases, error "ping request could not find host first_alias" is returned.
I have also tried to configure Apache on guest to have different port for each app, I have edited /etc/hosts file, forwarded ports in Vagrantfile, reload Apache service and Vagrant. This configuration also worked for all apps only in web browser on guest machine.
Thank you for any advise.
